# How to go about creating subdirectory web applications in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, saas

I want to build a web application that gives users their own instance of the application located on a sub-directory domain. For instance if it were a blogging platform they would get "yourblog.blogwebapp.com". Should I create a new website on Azure for each sub-domain site or should they be created in an existing website's virtual application section? If I do go the new website route I would somehow have to make sure their domain is "yourblog.blogwebapp.com" and I'm not sure if it's possible. Also, I'm not sure if you can programatically add virtual applications on the fly and if you can do it with out having to re-start the whole website.

I guess if someone can point me into the right direction via MSDN or blog post that would be great.

Comment: I don't have a resource handy, but I will say this is possible using just URL rewriting; you will need to be hosting on a dedicated IP address. I currently use this same technique on a site so users can have username.example.com (which just does a rewrite to example.com/site/?u=username). URL rewriting is definitely what you need here though to avoid having to mess with server settings and create subdomains on the fly.

Comment: What if some time down the road they want to use their own domain instead of user.example.com and SSL? I'm guessing it'll have to run on its own Azure website then, correct?

Comment: Using a custom domain is possible too. I'll have to dig up some old code but I've definitely done it. Not fully sure about SSL though.

Comment: I posted an answer below. It may or may not answer all of your questions, but I included some code for a rewrite rule that I've used in the past. It wasn't perfect, but it worked in the context that I had it.

Answer (score 0):

Per our discussion in the comments, following is the URL rewrite rule I used in the past to allow users to use custom domains. You'd have to test whether this is usable with SSL certs (I imagine it might be tricky since at the very least you'd need to install SSL certs for those domains).

The key with this approach is that you'd have to have something in your data store that knows a domain name is associated with a user. So, on the final redirect to `Page.aspx?d={R:1}` you could look up the requested domain and then redirect to a specific user's page. As an example, if you rewrite to `Page.aspx?d=www.example.com` then presumably somewhere in your data store, a user has "registered" that domain name to their account and verified it, possibly via email validation, and then you can rightfully load their content.

The Regular Expression I had in my code was not precise (and I am currently not using this feature on my site) so I didn't provide it below, but it should be fairly straightforward to set up. What you *could* do is have a rule which detects your main domain name and does nothing and stops processing, then after it you have another rule to detect all other domain names for which you can do the rewrite. Hopefully that makes sense. If not, let me know and I can clarify.

```
<rewrite>
    <rule name="UserDomain" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="(.*)" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="*** regex to detect domain names ***" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/Page.aspx?d={R:1}" />
    </rule>
</rewrite>
```